# Maven: Dependencia no encontrada

Tags: java, maven

Trato de añadir una dependencia, pero esta me marca lo siguiente:

> `[ERROR] /root/evolplus/backendEvol/evolplus/icova/icova-service/src/main/java/com/applying/icova/service/IdeaServiceImpl.java:[10,42] package org.apache.commons.text.similarity does not exist`

La dependencia en cuestión es [`commons-text`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/dependency-info.html).

He tratado todas las formas y no he podido añadirlo aún, trato lo siguiente:

1. Descargar el [`jar`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommontext105jar.htm).
2. Añadirlo de la siguiente [manera](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/dependency-info.html), sin error.

Mi árbol de directorios es así:

```
./icova
./pom.xml

./icova/icova-service
./icova/pom.xml
```

Es este archivo `pom.xml` que contiene la dependencia que no puedo instalar.

Trato de añadir el `jar` y borro la dependencia del archivo `pom.xml`, luego ejecuto `mvn clean package install` y sus variantes:

> `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project icova-service: Compilation failure`

> `[ERROR] /root/evolplus/backendEvol/evolplus/icova/icova-service/src/main/java/com/applying/icova/service/IdeaServiceImpl.java:[10,42] package org.apache.commons.text.similarity does not exist`

Supongo que es porque no encuentra la dependencia en cuestión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba añadiendo un -U a la hora de ejecutar tu comando de compilación. Por ejemplo:

```
mvn clean package -U
```

El `-U` fuerza la actualización de dependencias, así asegurarías que la descarga se realiza.

Es posible que hayas tenido algún problema previo en la descarga de la librería y, en esos casos, maven almacena en el repositorio local un fichero de extensión `.lastUpdated` para esa librería y no realiza de nuevo la descarga hasta pasar un tiempo determinado. Para forzar la descarga se usa el parámetro -U.

Por otro lado y ya como sugerencia, descarga mejor la versión 1.0 (la enlazada desde su github), que será más estable.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es porque no encuentra la dependencia. Si estás usando Archiva o similar puede que esté cacheando. La dependencia debería estar en el directorio repository de maven. en mi caso ../.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-text/1.0/commons-text-1.0-sources.jar 
De no estar puede ser por un problema de permisos, espacio, etc.

- Prueba a borrar la carpeta y hacer un **mvn clean install** para ver si descarga la dependencia.

Comment: Borrar la carpeta equivaldría a ejecutar el clean install -U